# Set up multiple Auto Return Urls for Paypal - one for each store view

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal, payment, paypal-standard

i am trying to set up different Auto Return Urls to work with Magento Pyapal payment Standard. I am running Magento 1.8.0.

In my Magento setup i have different store views (one for each language) and i have the store codes active, so one store will be www.storename.com/en/ while the other will be www.storename.com/de/ ....

**How can i setup the Auto Return Urls to be store view specific?** In my Paypal account i went to `Profile` → `Selling tools` → `Website preferences` and then set http://www.storename.com/paypal/standard/success/ as return url.

I did the same in the sandbox.paypal account because now i am using sandbox for testing purposes.

It still happens that after the payment has been done, Paypal does not automatically redirect to the success page. Instead it shows the Paypal payment confirmation page with 2 links:

- Go back to the website: info@storename.com
- Go to your account

*I am not using the english version of Paypal so maybe the translations differ a little bit, but i hope you got the idea.*

Anyway, shouldn't the Auto Return Url get the user directly to the success page on the Magento installation instead of displaying those 2 links? If this is the case, how can i get it to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My bad sorry, what i wrote above is the correct procedure. Once the return url has been specified in Paypal it will be overridden by Magento, even if you are using different store views each of which has different url codes, you have to define only one "figurative" url in Paypal.

The problem i had was that i did not create the correct account on Paypal sandbox, but after some trials and by activating the Debug on the Paypal settings on Magento and checking the .log file i understood that everything was working fine.